# Can we design arbitrary complex slalom tours?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, soft-question, complex-integration

Can we systematically design functions $f(z)$, so that:

$$\left\|\int_{z_0}^{z_{n+1}} f(z)dz\right\|$$

Is guaranteed to be minimal if we pass each of the points $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ along the curve of integration from alternating "sides" like in slalom?

I would imagining it would be possible by placing poles at the specific points and tuning their amplitude somehow but it was ages ago I took analysis in one complex variable.

Comment: "Let $M$ be an orientable 2-manifold on whose exterior there is a layer of snow..."

Comment: just to clarify: $f$ should be holomorphic, and the poles should *not* be the $z_i$, right?

Comment: The poles are allowed to be the $z_1,\cdots z_n$ so i suppose meromorphic. But it was ages ago i studied this.

Comment: if the poles are at the $z_i$ then I don't see what you mean by slalowing around the $z_i$. it sounds to me like you'd want to take say your poles and the $z_i$ in $\mathbb R$, with one pole between each consecutive $z_i$. no?

Comment: no.................................